# Count total items in mongoDB collection/database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongojs

I can't seem to find the answer to this. I wan't a simple return statement of the amount (total) items in my collections.

```
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs("myadb",['myadb']);
db.myadb.count(function(used,a){
    console.log(used,a);
});
```

Null is return. I'm using a mongodb JS library for node and yes, there is records in the database (12)

[The documentation states that:](http://mafintosh.github.io/mongojs/)

```
cursor.count(callback)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "null is return". The parameters to the [`count`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#count) callback are an error object (if any) and the count.  So in your callback, `a` will contain the count, not `used`. Is that not happening?

Comment: The document states that : `db.collection.count([query], callback)` for collections which is your case here.
`db.myadb` is not a cursor but a collection.

Comment: You don't have {query} in your .count() function...

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.count({},(err, data) => {
  console.log('err ', err, 'data ', data);
})
```